# FullCalendar: fetch events array on custom button click

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Running fullcalendar control angular project which is available on the author site.

After adding a custom button, I need to retrieve events from the full calendar control ([getEventSources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventSources)) with the click event:

```
customButtons: {
  myCustomButton: {
    text: 'Update',
    click: function() {
      debugger;
      alert('clicked the custom button!');
    }
  }
},
```

How I could get calendar object inside click method. I am using Angular project: [FullCalendar Angular](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular)

**AppComponent code:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FullCalendarComponent, CalendarOptions, DateSelectArg, EventClickArg, EventApi, CalendarApi, Calendar, DateEnv, getDateMeta, CalendarContent, CalendarDataManager, CalendarRoot, triggerDateSelect,} from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId,getRecentMonthEvents } from './event-utils';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { THIS_EXPR } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { global } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;    

constructor()
{
  this.calendarMonth = (new Date().getMonth() + 1);
  this.calendarYear = new Date().getFullYear();

}
  calendarVisible = true;
  public calendarMonth: number;
  public calendarYear: number;
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth'//,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    weekends: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,

    eventContent: function(arg) {
  
      var ProdCnt = arg.event.extendedProps.budgetDailyNumber;
      let toggleSwitch = document.createElement('LABEL');
      toggleSwitch.className = "switch";

      if (arg.event.extendedProps.isWorkDay) {
        toggleSwitch.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox"><span class="slider round"></span><br>';
      } else {
        toggleSwitch.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" checked><span class="slider round"></span><br>';
      }
      let textBox = document.createElement('input');
      textBox.setAttribute("type", "text");
      textBox.setAttribute("value", ProdCnt);
      textBox.setAttribute("style", "width: 20px;height: 20px;background-color: white;");
  
      let arrayOfDomNodes = [ toggleSwitch,textBox ]
      return { domNodes: arrayOfDomNodes }
    },

    customButtons: {
  myCustomButton: {
    text: 'Update',
    click:  function() {
    
      alert('clicked the custom button!');
    }
  }
},
select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this),
initialDate: new Date(), 
// viewRender: function(view, element) {
//   var b = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
//   alert(b.format('L'));
// },

events: {
  //getCalendarMonth
  
  url: 'http://localhost:50324/api/productionforecast?month=' + environment.calMonth +'&year=' + environment.calYear,
  //url: 'http://localhost:50324/api/productionforecast?month=' +(new Date().getMonth() + 1)+'&year=' + (new Date().getFullYear()),
  method: 'GET',
  failure: function() {
    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
  },
  color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
  textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
}

/* you can update a remote database when these fire:
eventAdd:
eventChange:
eventRemove:
*/
  };
  currentEvents: EventApi[] = [];

  handleCalendarToggle() {
    this.calendarVisible = !this.calendarVisible;

  }

  handleWeekendsToggle() {
    const { calendarOptions } = this;
    calendarOptions.weekends = !calendarOptions.weekends;
  }
  handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
    const title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event');
    const calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

    calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

if (title) {
  calendarApi.addEvent({
    id: createEventId(),
    title,
    start: selectInfo.startStr,
    end: selectInfo.endStr,
    allDay: selectInfo.allDay
  });
}
  }

  handleEventClick(clickInfo: EventClickArg) {
    if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the event     '${clickInfo.event.title}'`)) {
          clickInfo.event.remove();
    }
      }

  handleEvents(events: EventApi[]) {
    this.currentEvents = events;
  }
getCalendarMonth()
{
  debugger;
  return this.calendarComponent.getApi().getDate().getMonth();
}
public loadProductionforecast(month, year)
{


  //   this.appService.getProductionforecast(month, year).subscribe((data: any) => {
  //   debugger;

}

}
```

**Problems:**

1. In the Click event of custom button named as **myCustomButton**, we cannot access **calendarComponent** object.
2. When we click on prev/next buttons, it calls events(Get API call) where I need to pass next/prev month and year parameters.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this question without more of the surrounding code? Do you already have a reference to the calendar object you want to include when defining this click function? If so, you may have to bind the function to this scope (depending on the surrounding code), but you would just use the reference in your click function.

Comment: If you're using the ready-made fullCalendar Angular component, then https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular already tells you how to get the calendar object (in the "Calendar API" section).

Comment: @SalmanRafique StackOverflow guidelines are to post relevant details not link them. Besides I can not access your link (at least not from my work computer).

Comment: @JeffreyP, I have edit my post with complete code. Please review thanks

Comment: @ADyson, I have edit my post. I have followed Calendar API section but could not get calendarComponent object in custom button clink method. Please review.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually request the API object correctly as per the instructions in the documentation. (Well, you did it in the getCalendarMonth function but a) you aren't using that function for anything and b) it doesn't expose the API object to the rest of the code. Was there something in the documentation which you didn't understand?

Comment: And when you say you "cannot access calendarComponent object."...what does that actually mean? Do you get a specific error when you try to use it. Bear in mind that `this` may be a different object inside a callback, as the context is different.

Comment: @ADyson, I have declared calendarComponent object in the same way as mentioned in the Calendar API section, and then I tried to access it like "this.calendarComponent" inside the custom button click method, this object is not available in the chrome debugging and getAPI() call raise an error of undefined object. Please address this issue.

Comment: @ADyson, getCalendarMonth method is commented, and with the given URL I have successfully render events. I need to give month and year number in dynamic way. So with prev and next button clicks, I need to pass correct month and year in URL parameters.

Comment: Like I said, I'd assume it's because the scope of `this` may be different inside the click callback. I suggest assigning a reference to `this` to another variable name (somewhere outside the callback, but which would have scope inside it), and then using that within the callback to try and access the component.

Comment: Regarding the month - if you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed you'll understand that when you define your event feed as a URL, as you have done, then fullCalendar will automatically send the current start and end dates of the calendar to your server, as parameters in the request. So you don't need to write any additional JS code to let your server know the data to return, it's already handled automatically for you. All you have to do is make your API read the incoming dates and filter the returned data accordingly.

Comment: right, I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside click event of the custom button, we can access call app component method like this:

```
customButtons: {
  myCustomButton: {
    text: 'Update',
    click: () => this.customFunction()
  }
}
```